# Change bibitem color in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex

In beamer one can use the option `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]` to replace the standard beamer bibliography icon for numeric-style items.

I would like to change the color of the resulting numeric items since they are blue by default.

The option `\setbeamercolor*{}` enables changing the color of other bibliography entries (e.g. title, author, etc.). However, I tried things like `\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry item}{fg=black}` or even changing the hyperref options `\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=black,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black}`, but I still get blue numeric items. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: `\setbeamercolor*{bibliography item}{fg=black}` sholud work

Comment: Perfect, that worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\setbeamercolor*{bibliography item}{fg=black}` can be used to change the color of the bibliography item in a `beamer`presentation.

`bibliography entry ...` with `...`= `author`, `title`, `location` or `note` refers to the corresponding parts of the references in the bibliography.